# Has anybody encountered strange behavior of LOOKUP()?

Tags: excel, excel-2007

**NOTE:** I don't need a solution for the actual problem to be solved with Excel. I want to understand and discuss the behaviour. And I want to see, if other people can reproduce the situation and make them aware of it.

- *Situation is extremely simplified for debugging the problem.*
- *I use **Excel 2007** in an cooperate environment*

In a calculation made on a two-week basis, I have to fill in numbers for the two-week interval that are valid a whole month. For example first two weeks of December I have to use value `12`, second two weeks again, than first to weeks of January I have to use `1`, second two weeks again.

[image]

Therefore I have a column for each two-week period with a field of current month (green area in screenshot). The values valid for the month are in a second table (red area). To retrieve the value for current period, I use a `LOOKUP()`call:

```
(A2): =LOOKUP(A1;$A$9:$H$9;$A$10:$H$10)
...
(P2): =LOOKUP(P1;$A$9:$H$9;$A$10:$H$10)
```

As you can see in the screenshot, the function goes havoc and retrieves false values.

For testing, I reproduced the situation with the international phonetic alphabet instead of month names. Therefore:

```
(A5): =LOOKUP(A4;$A$12:$H$12;$A$13:$H$13)
...
```

This time, the function works well. Therefore I guess, it has something to do with the name of months. Maybe they have some internal representation, despite the fact, the cell are formatted as "text".

I already tested vertical vectors instead of horizontals in the red area. They lead to the same situation.

**NOTE:**

I finally solved the original problem by using `HLOOKUP()` and `VLOOKUP()`. There I found another clue. Both show the same behaviour if `[not_exact_match]` is committed or set to true but work fine, if `exact_match` is enforced. So, how can *Februar* be an approximate match to *Dezember*?

Comment: @pnuts: Granted. But just a matching string should not trigger your reaction. The link is about "Chatty, open-ended questions", while "I would like others to explain ______ to me" is "probably OK". My intention was to understand the behaviour and not get an answer like "just use `HLOOKUP()`" because I already did that.

Comment: Okay. The primer was even enough for me. Somehow that always slipped me. Could be, that I use german excel, searching for SVERWEIS and WVERWEIS instead. I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/lookup-function-HP010342671.aspx

For the LOOKUP function to work correctly, the data being looked up must be sorted in ascending order.

This is not the case with the texts "Dezember", "Januar", "Februar", ...

If you would use real dates 01.12.2013, 01.01.2014, 01.02.2014, ... and format them as "MMMM", then it should work. Of course the lookup_value also has to be in that form.

Same problem with VLOOKUP and not exact match. http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx

If range_lookup is either TRUE or is omitted, the values in the first column of table_array must be placed in ascending sort order; otherwise, VLOOKUP might not return the correct value.

Comment: That means, in my example, Excel looks up February, finds December, then January, expects _F_ to be in between _D_ and _J_ and stops looking, using December value, because _D_ is nearer to _F_ then _J_?

Comment: The search method used is an implementation of binary search. This method does NOT find an approximate match if the data is not sorted: it just produces mostly random answers.

Comment: See binary search algorthim: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Looks up "Februar", finds "März" in the middle (at the end of the first half), which is greater, so "Februar" has to be in first half. Finds "Januar" in the middle of first half, which is greater too, so "Februar" has to be in the first quarter. Finds "Dezember", which is lower, and takes this as result.